# Android: Making spinners appear after an option in another spinner is selected

Tags: android, spinner

I would like to know if it is possible to make spinners appear below a spinner with text based on the selected spinner.  Basically, lets say there are 3 spinners (A, B, C).  I want B and C to appear after anything from A is selected (besides the default option).  I want C to appear then after anything besides the default is selected from spinner B.

I have found resources with dynamically populating a spinner from a database which is partially what I am trying to do.  Does anyone have any suggestions or am I going to have to just have the enabled permissions change on currently placed spinners?

Answer (score 0):

just On selection listener of the first spinner, call a function to populate the second spinner and set it visible.